# Should we remove observer in dealloc for UIView?

Tags: objective-c

```
-(void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:USERBOOKMARKANDLIKEOBTAINED object:nil];
}
```

I mean, doesn't the observer remove the object when it's about deallocated? I've heard they use nil pointing pointer to the observer or something. Or what about is the notification keep strong reference to the object and that means dealloc will never be called anyway (memory leak).

So is what I do correct?

The class inherits from UIView by the way.

Comment: Only tag with "xcode" if the question is about Xcode. It isn't.

Comment: Well, anyone here use objective-c without xcode? Also I am asking the way things behave in standard xcode enviroment. Don't know if gcc or other compiler works the same way and don't care.

Comment: 1. It's me (I don't use Xcode for programming, it's crap; clang and make does the job, furthermore there's no other option in the case of on-device development). 2. Yes, the compilers don't know who calls him - an IDE, a programmer, `make` or whatever else. Therefore general iOS programming questions should be tagged 'C' or 'Objective-C' (depending on the language of the API used) and 'cocoa-touch'. Now please go read the tag wiki for 'xcode', you'll find the same advice there.

Comment: You use clang without xcode? What are you? I had a hard time programming even with all the human GUI feature.

Comment: I'm not surprised. "Nice" graphical IDEs **are** confusing (and often enforce bad programming practices.

Comment: They enforce awesome programming practice like autocomplete and pre compile checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean, doesn't the observer remove it self when the object is about to be destroyed anyway?

It does, if you use the code you provided. Else it doesn't. (How would the notification center know an object is deallocated?)

Comment: So when an object is being deallocated, it doesn't send notification everywhere?

Comment: @JimThio No, magic and miracles are not yet implemented in the Objective-C runtime (maybe in 3.0 :P)

Comment: I guess I'll just remove notification till that happen.

Comment: For now I'll just add bug report for lack of magic and miracles